# QGIS won't display GML features

Tags: qgis, fme-form, gml

I have a 90 MB GML with about 3000 features but QGIS only shows the first three. The fourth feature is a multipart polyline. This an the extract of the feature:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <FeatureCollection xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2" gml:id="id-87c8d6ee-112c-4408-a26e-3d7158f27c2b">
<featureMember>
  <Feature gml:id="id-54a7d56e-ce1f-404e-b875-fd06e74f8ee5">
<attribute1></attribute1>
[...]
      <geometry>
             <gml:MultiCurve gml:id="id-fdb29aca-2c23-48a1-a513-168f6e711bb0-0" srsName="EPSG:3035" srsDimension="3">
               <gml:curveMember>
                 <gml:LineString gml:id="id-fdb29aca-2c23-48a1-a513-168f6e711bb0-1">
                   <gml:posList>Coordinates</gml:posList>
                 </gml:LineString>
              </gml:curveMember>
              <gml:curveMember>
                <gml:LineString gml:id="id-fdb29aca-2c23-48a1-a513-168f6e711bb0-2">
                  <gml:posList>Coordinates</gml:posList>
                </gml:LineString>
              </gml:curveMember>
      </geometry>
  </Feature></FeatureCollection>
```

Is the geometry tag well formed? Or it is just that QGIS cannot render? BTW, the GML was generated with FME and I have no problems to render in FME.

Comment: If I remove the feature I can see more features in QGIS, just until the next multipart polyline.

Comment: Try to prepare multipolyline in new shp layer then export it to GML and compare with posted structure.

Comment: It would be good to see your FME workspace.  How you created the GML...  As GML is a type of XML, there are a lot of XML transformers that can help you.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you don't close `<gml:MultiCurve>` in `<geometry>`.

I used Notepad++ with XML plugin to check the syntax and correct the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FeatureCollection xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2" gml:id="id-87c8d6ee-112c-4408-a26e-3d7158f27c2b">
    <featureMember>
        <Feature gml:id="id-54a7d56e-ce1f-404e-b875-fd06e74f8ee5">
            <geometry>
                <gml:MultiCurve gml:id="id-fdb29aca-2c23-48a1-a513-168f6e711bb0-0" srsName="EPSG:3035" srsDimension="3">
                    <gml:curveMember>
                        <gml:LineString gml:id="id-fdb29aca-2c23-48a1-a513-168f6e711bb0-1">
                            <gml:posList>1 2 3 4 5 6</gml:posList>
                        </gml:LineString>
                    </gml:curveMember>
                    <gml:curveMember>
                        <gml:LineString gml:id="id-fdb29aca-2c23-48a1-a513-168f6e711bb0-2">
                            <gml:posList>7 8 9 10 11 12</gml:posList>
                        </gml:LineString>
                    </gml:curveMember>
                </gml:MultiCurve>
            </geometry>
        </Feature>
    </featureMember>
</FeatureCollection>
```

Geometry shows fine in QGIS 2.16.0.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use the option to skip those GML features that it doesn't understand[[image: QGIS options]]

It wont solve the problem of not reading some geometries but at least it will render those that it can without stoping early in the process